# Should I use "besides" or "apart from" in the following sentences?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> She couldn't talk with other people **besides/apart from** Mom and Dad.
>
> He wasn't an expert in anything **besides/apart from** math and history.

Should it be "besides" or "apart from?" Or maybe both are correct since they mean the same thing?

Comment: To some extent, ***apart from*** is a "negative polarity" element, and ***besides*** is "positive polarity". So you should prefer *She **likes** other people **besides** me*, and *She **doesn't like** other people **apart from** me*, rather than the other way around.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I've never thought about it that way. So, according to this logic, I should use "apart from" in both sentences?

Comment: My "you should prefer..." and "to some extent" both imply *that's the "better" choice* (but you don't *have* to follow that advice). Whereas your "I should use..." implies the alternative is actually ***incorrect***. It's not - it's just "less good" (***in my opinion***, but others may not make this distinction).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Besides** means *including*. **Apart from** means *excluding*. In this sense, *'apart from'* is similar to *'except for'*.
Let us make it clear with two examples;

> Besides John, I invited all the boys.
> It means I invited John.

> Apart from John, I invited all the boys.
> It means I didn't invite John.

> She could not talk with other people besides Mom and Dad.
> It means she could not talk with Mom and Dad.

> She could not talk with other people apart from Mom and Dad.
> It means she could talk with Mom and Dad.

> He wasn't an expert in anything besides math and history.
> It means he wasn't an expert in math and history.

> He wasn't an expert in anything apart from math and history.
> It means he was an expert in math and history.

Answer (score 1):

They are both correct. I would say that "besides" is informal and "apart from" is more formal. Probably the *most* formal would be "excepting"

Comment: I think ***but*** is a fairly formal [poetic?] alternative to ***apart from***. As in [*They had no friends **but** each other.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22no+friends+but+each+other%22) But yeah - ***excepting*** might be even *more* "formal, starchy" in that context (*if* I could find it in Google Books, which I can't! :)

Comment: Or just 'except'?